# Asana PHP API Connection Error : 443

Tags: php, ssl, asana, asana-api

I am trying to use the Asana PHP API to build a browser project for personal use, but I am facing problems with connecting to the API.

This is the response i get when trying to fetch the user data from the API.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Httpful\Exception\ConnectionErrorException' with message 'Unable to connect to "https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/users/me": 35 Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to app.asana.com:443 ' in php-asana\vendor\nategood\httpful\src\Httpful\Request.php:208

Here is the code I am using for initializing and fetching the data

```
require 'php-asana/vendor/autoload.php';
$client = Asana\Client::accessToken(PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN);
$users = $client->users->me();
print_r($users);
```

The app is set up on my local server. Is it necessary for the client server to have SSL in order to fetch data from the Asana API or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Were you able to get this working?

Comment: Yeah, my local server was using a deprecated version of TLS. Updating it fixed the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be using a deprecated version of TLS to do your requests, please see [Asana is now deactivating TLS 1.0](https://asana.com/developers/feed/tls-10-shutoff)

Additionally, the library you are using [may not support secure connections](https://github.com/nategood/httpful/issues/230)